# How to Map Repository (DAL/UnitOfWork.cs) with ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository, mapping, viewmodel

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am using unit of work and repository for data access. Currently the code directly uses domain model to access database. I've been trying to make ViewModel(SystemAdminViewModel) interact with Generic Repository instead of Model. How is it possible?

Here's how the code looks like:

Controllers/SystemAdminController.cs

```
public class SystemAdminController : Controller
{

    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

    //
    // GET: /SystemAdmin/
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        //Constant for System Admin List
        ViewBag.Title = Settings.Default.SystemAdminList;
        var systemAdmin = unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.Get().ToList();
        return View(systemAdmin);
    }

    //
    // GET: /SystemAdmin/Details/5
    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        SystemAdmin systemAdmin = unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.GetByID(id);
        return View(systemAdmin);
    }

    //
    // GET: /SystemAdmin/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //Constant for System Admin List
        ViewBag.Title = Settings.Default.AddSystemAdmin;
        ViewBag.BackToList = Settings.Default.BackToSystemAdminList;
        ViewBag.AddTitle = Settings.Default.AddSystemAdmin;

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /SystemAdmin/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(
        [Bind(Include = "ID,Username,Password,Status")]
     SystemAdmin systemAdmin)
    {
        //Constant for System Admin List
        ViewBag.Title = Settings.Default.AddSystemAdmin;
        ViewBag.BackToList = Settings.Default.BackToSystemAdminList;
        ViewBag.AddTitle = Settings.Default.AddSystemAdmin;

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.Insert(systemAdmin);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(systemAdmin);
    }

    //
    //GET: SystemAdmin/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //Constant for System Admin List
        ViewBag.EditTitle = Settings.Default.EditSystemAdmin;
        ViewBag.BackToList = Settings.Default.BackToSystemAdminList;

        SystemAdmin systemAdmin = unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.GetByID(id);
        return View(systemAdmin);
    }

    //
    //POST: SystemAdmin/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(
         [Bind(Include = "ID,Username,Password,Status")]
     SystemAdmin systemAdmin)
    {
        //Constant for System Admin List
        ViewBag.EditTitle = Settings.Default.EditSystemAdmin;
        ViewBag.BackToList = Settings.Default.BackToSystemAdminList;

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.Update(systemAdmin);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(systemAdmin);
    }

    //
    // GET: /SystemAdmin/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        SystemAdmin systemAdmin = unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.GetByID(id);
        return View(systemAdmin);
    }

    //
    // POST: /SystemAdmin/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        SystemAdmin systemAdmin = unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.GetByID(id);
        unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.Delete(id);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        unitOfWork.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

DAL/DineMonsterDBContext.cs

```
public class DineMonsterDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SystemAdmin> SystemAdmins { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SystemAdmin>();
    }
}
```

DAL/UnitOfWork.cs

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable    
{
    private DineMonsterDBContext context = new DineMonsterDBContext();
    private GenericRepository<SystemAdmin> systemAdminRepository;
    private GenericRepository<SystemAdminViewModel> systemAdminVMRepository;

    public GenericRepository<SystemAdmin> SystemAdminRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.systemAdminRepository == null)
            {
                this.systemAdminRepository = new GenericRepository<SystemAdmin>(context);
            }
            return systemAdminRepository;
        }
    }
```

DAL/GenericRepository.cs

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DineMonsterDBContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DineMonsterDBContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
    public GenericRepository<SystemAdminViewModel> SystemAdminVMRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.systemAdminVMRepository == null)
            {
                this.systemAdminVMRepository = new GenericRepository<SystemAdminViewModel>(context);
            }
            return systemAdminVMRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

DAL/IGenericRepository.cs

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> Get();
    T GetByID(object id);
    void Insert(T obj);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Update(T obj);
    void Save();
}
```

Models/SystemAdminViewModel.cs

```
public class SystemAdminViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Username can contain only 20 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password does not match")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public SystemAdminViewModel()
    {
        this.Status = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that you're new, allow me to save you some pain. Throw away all the repository and unit of work junk. I imagine you got that from the ASP.NET site, but despite the source, it is *not* a good method. An ORM like Entity Framework *is* your unit of work and each `DbSet` *is* a repository. All you're doing is adding an extra layer that does nothing but require more maintenance, additional tests, etc., for no gain.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a method that map SystemAdmin to SystemAdminViewModel or use a library  like  [automapper](http://automapper.org/) and in your controller use from it loke

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    //Constant for System Admin List
    ViewBag.Title = Settings.Default.SystemAdminList;
    var systemAdmin = unitOfWork.SystemAdminRepository.Get().ToList();
    var systemAdminVM=Mapper.Map<SystemAdmin ,SystemAdminViewModel>(systemAdmin);//your mapper usage
    return View(systemAdmin);
}
```